# Spotfire data format from Oracle database

Tags: oracle, spotfire

I am pulling data from an Oracle database into Spotfire.  For some reason, Spotfire formats all numbers as currency with 2 decimals.  In my data sets there are a significant number of columns that should be integers. Having them come in as currency doesn't cause any calculation issues that I've found, but it is a formatting issue when columns that obviously should not have decimals are displaced with them.
I have tried using the CAST AS SMALLINT, INTEGER, and also ROUND in my SQL statements to try and get rid of the decimal places.  So far, they have all been unsuccessful.

Any ideas on how I can get Spotfire to import numbers with the desired format, or am I going to have to manually change them after they are imported?

Below is an example of some of the functions I have tried.

```
>     SELECT
>      
>        NAME,
>     
>        CAST(X_ID AS SMALLINT) X_ID,
>     
>        CAST(Y_ID AS INTEGER) Y_ID,
>     
>        ROUND(Z_ID,0) AS Z_ID,
>     
>     FROM TABLE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spotfire is importing It to the largest most precise data type needed. If you want to display it differently then simply go to Edit > Column Properties, click on the column in question and change the format. You can also do this for each individual chart if you don’t want to make a global change

Comment: scsimon,  Thanks for your response.  I know that I can change the format and data type once the data is in spotifire, but I would like to figure out how to get the data in the system with the correct format to begin with.  I'm pulling in some decent sized data sets with 20+ columns, and manually changing each of them is rather tedious.

Comment: in this case, i'd make a view in your database of this data where you handle the casting / converting. It's simply inheriting the datatype. If the datatype was an integer in the database (no decimals present) then it should default to INT.